# the inside of LIB etc. is coded with pure C++ code?

Tags: c++

For example, Is std string coded with only reserved word?
like char[],int(for recoding length),override = +.
std string don't seem to add new grammar or new reserved word.

As above, are ALL STL or Header files essentially pure c++ code?

Comment: There's no requirement how the standard library is implemented.  If you depend on specific implementation details, you'll need to check your library's documentation.

Comment: Certainly not. Try to write `std::iostream` in pure C++ without using any built-in printing functions from C++. The standard library is most certainly calling out to things outside the purview of C++ to do "dirty work" like printing, file access, and many other things. *Parts* of the C++ standard library (like, say, `std::vector`) could probably be re-implemented in C++ if desired, but definitely not all of it.

Comment: The standard just specifies the interface by which C++ code accesses library facilities, and required behaviour. That's doesn't mean everything must be implemented in C++.  That said, some facilities in the standard library (like containers and algorithms) CAN be implemented in standard C++ (but vendors may implement them in another language, say for performance reasons).  Some facilities cannot be totally implemented in standard C++ (e.g. `<iostream>` typically uses OS-specific functions that may not be implemented in C++ (or C)) or rely on "compiler magic" (e.g. type support facilities).

Comment: Perhaps what you really want to know is if the STL has access to special private features of the compiler that other C++ code does not have access to?  If so, the answer is, it very well may; that’s an implementation detail so it’s up to the compiler-vendor.